# R Language Color Coding Points on Existing Graph

Tags: r, graph

I am following along with the MITx: 15.071x The Analytics Edge course online and am trying to determine how to color code points on graph. I can successfully make a graph of latitude and longitude using line 1 one below. However, when I try the second line I just get a blank graph. When I leave the original graph from line 1 in focus I can't type any code without returning focus to console, and then typing line two does not do anything. I am new to both stackoverflow and R so any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

1. `plot(boston$LON, boston$LAT)`
2. `points(boston$LON[boston$CHAS == 1], boston$LAST[boston$CHAS ==1], col = "blue", pch = 19)`

Comment: So your goal is color code each point according to a third column (presumably called `CHAS`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it on one plot call:

```
plot(boston$LON, boston$LAT, 
                   col=c("black", "blue")[ (boston$CHAS==1)+1 ] )
```

This uses implicit coercion (via the `+1` operation) of a logical vector formed by `(boston$CHAS==1)` from FALSE/TRUE (or {0,1}) to {1,2} which then is used to index from the color vector. Such color vectors are called palettes in R. The `findInterval` function would allow you to compactly create a multiple valued integer vector that could select from a much larger color palette vector.

(Your method should have succeeded in plotting blue points on the plot that was formed by the first line, but perhaps it was the misspelling of "LAT" that tripped you up?)

Answer (score 1):

The function `points` can be used only once the function `plot` has been called previously, so you could call the following sequentially

```
plot(mtcars$disp[mtcars$cyl==4],mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==4],col='red',pch=16,ylim=range(mtcars$mpg),xlim=range(mtcars$disp))
points(mtcars$disp[mtcars$cyl==6],mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==6],col='blue',pch=16)
points(mtcars$disp[mtcars$cyl==8],mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl==8],col='black',pch=16)
```

[image]

You might also look at the package `ggplot2` which makes this kind of thing more simple

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=disp,y=mpg,color=factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the ggplot tip.